# Firebird indexes - create and use

Tags: indexing, firebird, firebird2.5, firebird2.1

For an existing table in our database,

if I create an index on a table such as:

```
create index i_system_code_system_type_no on system_code (SYSTEM_TYPE_NO);
```

and then set statistics:

```
set statistics index i_system_code_system_type_no;
```

when executing a query against the table which "should" use the index, doesn't.  For whatever reason, the optimizer I'm guessing (unless I've missed something), doesn't feel it's the best approach.  However, if I restart the Firebird Guardian service, it does use it.

Does it take time for the server to catch up and build the index?  Short of me forcing the index to use in the actual query itself is there a way to update or do something else to tell the server to use my new index?  I can tell its using the new index because the "Adapted Plan" shows it using the index, plus the query execution time drops from about 0.5 sec to "instant".

This new index will be applied to 00's of databases of our customers, so just trying to determine the best way to distribute this update without having to restart the individual services on each of the customers machines.

Comment: You need to provide more information: did you start a new transaction to execute the query. Was the query prepared in an earlier transaction? Visibility and usability of an index depends on time of transaction start **and** statement prepare time (which could have happened in an earlier transaction).

Comment: Yes.  Both would have been executed within the context of the same transaction.  If I look at the table metadata it shows the index there ok.  The Select query would be executed in it's own transaction and the index would be visible to that transaction.  I am sure it's not transaction related.    eg, I'm using IBExpert and executing those commands in SQL Editor and viewing table indexes shows everything, but even restarting IBExpert doesn't make it work until I restart the guardian.  Index is visible when restarting.

Comment: Then it is probably the meta data cache that is not getting cleared; I believe there isn't much you can do about that, but restarting the entire Firebird database server isn't necessary: with super server closing all connections to the database should be sufficient, with superclassic or classic restarting the individual connections would be.